# c++ read config binary file

Tags: c++, ifstream

I want to read a binary file which contains a start sequenz char[9] and a char[5] for 5 IDs. So i opened my file but I'm not sure how to correctly save my data.

```
char[8] start_sq = "STARTSEQ\n" // start of the binary file
```

after that there are 5 IDs.

So how can I set my starting postion after the start_sq

```
int current_pos = 0;
std:ifstream readFile_;
int *id;
while( (current_pos = (readFile_.tellg())) == eof) 
{
   //start after start_sq // not sure how to
   int tmp_id = readFile_.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&id), sizeof(int)); // should be first ID (OR?)
  ids.push_back(tmo_id);
  // again for ID 2 

}
```

I get it, if my question is a bit unclear at first. but I not sure how to correctly implement that. but as you can see i have a few ideas/approaches.

thx for any help :)

Comment: I suggest this reading : http://www.eecs.umich.edu/eecs/courses/eecs380/HANDOUTS/cppBinaryFileIO-2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would do :

[ *WARNING : the following is absolutely not tested !* ]

```
//int current_pos = 0;
std:ifstream readFile_;

... // Open the file in binary mode, etc...

//int *id;
char id;

// Read the 'STARTSEQ' string + 1 carriage return :
char[9] startseq;
readFile_.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&startseq[0]),  9);
//                                                    ^^^
// IMPORTANT : The above line shifts the current_pos of 9 bytes.
// Short : readFile_.read(startseq, sizeof(startseq));

// Then read your IDs
// You want your IDs as chars so let's read chars, not int.
while( readFile_.good() ) // or while( !readFile_.eof() ) 
{
   readFile_.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&id), sizeof(char));
   // IMPORTANT : The above line shifts the current_pos of 1 byte.
   // Short : readFile_.read(&id, 1);
   ids.push_back(id);
}
// The above 'while' loops until EOF is reached (aka. 5 times). 
// See ifstream.good(), ifstream.eof().
```

Note : The string to be read ("STARTSEQ\n") is 9 characters long, not 8.

Another approach for populating the `ids` vector could have been :

```
vector<char> ids;
int size = 5;
ids.resize(size);
// Read 'size' bytes (= chars) and store it in the 'ids' vector :
readFile_.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ids[0]), size);
```

Note : No `while` used here, but careful : no check if EOF is reached.

I hope that it is what you where asking for.